# XSLT Custom Sort with Symbols, Letters, and Numbers (O counts as a zero)

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a table with a series of rows of part numbers. I need to sort the output by a series of very specific sequence and can't figure out how to do the

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row">
    <xsl:sort select="row/partNumber"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

properly. I need them to be sort by:

1. Symbols (specifically a slash, then a period, then a dash)
2. Letters (except for the letter O)
3. Numbers (with the letter O counting as a 0)

Does anybody have any ideas?

edited to add:
I'm using XSLT 2.0 and saxon. And some of the sample data is

```
<row>
    <partNumber>AN931-4-13</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AN931.2</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AO931</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AP417-3</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AP417/3</partNumber>
</row>
```

It should output as:

```
AN931.2
AN931-4-13
AP417/3
AP417-3
AO931
```

Edited to add:
Here's the solution that I went with. I set the rules as a variable via

```
<xsl:variable name="rules">
     <xsl:text>&lt; '/' &lt; '.' &lt; '-' &lt; a,A &lt; b,B &lt; c,C &lt; d,D &lt; e,E &lt; f,F &lt; g,G &lt; h,H &lt; i,I &lt; j,J &lt; k,K &lt; l,L &lt; m,M &lt; n,N  &lt; p,P &lt; q,Q &lt; r,R &lt; s,S &lt; t,T &lt; u,U &lt; v,V &lt; w,W &lt; x,X &lt; y,Y &lt; z,Z &lt; 0 = o = O &lt; 1 &lt; 2 &lt; 3 &lt; 4 &lt; 5 &lt; 6 &lt; 7 &lt; 8 &lt; 9</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I just used

```
<xsl:sort select="partNumber" collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?rules={encode-for-uri($rules)}"/>
```

Comment: Can you post some examples of your input? Also which XSLT version and engine are you using?

Comment: I've added some sample data/desired output and mentioned that I'm using XSLT2.0 and Saxon.

Comment: Given that sample and `select="row"` on the `apply-templates` I would the `xsl:sort` expect to select `partNumber` and not `row/partNumber`. For the `O` to `0` I would use `translate` or `replace` on that `partNumber`, for the other treatment it would help if you tell us more of the Saxon version and edition you use as there might be collations that help.

Comment: It looks like it's the saxon9he.jar file. I'm not very familiar with the translates, would that basically have the sort select as `translate(substring(., 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN0PQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')`

Comment: The usual application to "translate" any `O` to `0` would be `translate(partNumber, 'O', '0')`

Comment: Saxon, through its configuration, allows you to declare your own "collation", that might make sense for your symbols, I guess. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/configuration/configuration-file/config-collations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to construct some collation rules for your syntax and feed it to the Saxon configuration, in the following sample done with XQuery 3.1 and the `transform` function and all configuration data inline:

```
transform(map {
  'source-node' : .,
  'stylesheet-node' : <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                expand-text="yes">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="rows">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
          <xsl:sort select="partNumber" collation="http://example.com/mc1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>,
  'vendor-options' : map {
     QName('http://saxon.sf.net/', 'configuration'): 
       <configuration xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration">
         <collations>
           <collation uri="http://example.com/mc1"
             alphanumeric="yes"
             rules="&lt; a,A &lt; b,B &lt; c,C &lt; d,D &lt; e,E &lt; f,F &lt; g,G &lt; h,H &lt; i,I &lt; j,J &lt; k,K &lt; l,L &lt; m,M &lt; n,N  &lt; p,P &lt; q,Q &lt; r,R &lt; s,S &lt; t,T &lt; u,U &lt; v,V &lt; w,W &lt; x,X &lt; y,Y &lt; z,Z &lt; 0 = o = O &lt; 1 &lt; 2 &lt; 3 &lt; 4 &lt; 5 &lt; 6 &lt; 7 &lt; 8 &lt; 9 &lt; '/' &lt; '.' &lt; '-'"/>           
         </collations>
       </configuration>
  }
}
)?output
```

For the input

```
<rows>
<row>
    <partNumber>AN931-4-13</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AN931.2</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AO931</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AP417-3</partNumber>
</row>
<row>
    <partNumber>AP417/3</partNumber>
</row>
</rows>
```

I get the output

```
<rows>
   <row>
      <partNumber>AN931.2</partNumber>
   </row>
   <row>
      <partNumber>AN931-4-13</partNumber>
   </row>
   <row>
      <partNumber>AP417/3</partNumber>
   </row>
   <row>
      <partNumber>AP417-3</partNumber>
   </row>
   <row>
      <partNumber>AO931</partNumber>
   </row>
</rows>
```

using Saxon 11.2 HE, now also tested online with 10.6 HE at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hwpia.

I hope, whatever Saxon 9 version you use, that you can just feed it an appropriate configuration file with an appropriate collation similar to or based on the one in the above sample. Or, as your comment points out, you can also inline the rules:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                
    <xsl:param name="rules" as="xs:string">&lt; a,A &lt; b,B &lt; c,C &lt; d,D &lt; e,E &lt; f,F &lt; g,G &lt; h,H &lt; i,I &lt; j,J &lt; k,K &lt; l,L &lt; m,M &lt; n,N  &lt; p,P &lt; q,Q &lt; r,R &lt; s,S &lt; t,T &lt; u,U &lt; v,V &lt; w,W &lt; x,X &lt; y,Y &lt; z,Z &lt; 0 = o = O &lt; 1 &lt; 2 &lt; 3 &lt; 4 &lt; 5 &lt; 6 &lt; 7 &lt; 8 &lt; 9 &lt; '/' &lt; '.' &lt; '-'</xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="rows">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
          <xsl:sort select="partNumber" collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?rules={encode-for-uri($rules)}"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The collation looks like it worked! Thank you so much! I was able to place the rules you came up with in a `<xsl:variable name="rules"...` and then set a `collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?rules={encode-for-uri($rules)}` on the sort so I didn't need to use an external configuration file.

Comment: @Sebastien, are you asking @Tom?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes I tried tagging him but it did not work.

Comment: @Tom Would you mind posting what you came up with as an answer, so it can be available for others later.

Comment: @Sebastien, I have added what I think Tom did.

Comment: @Sebastien, Martin had it. I edited my original question to throw in what I went with too since it's prettier than in the comments.